# Does multiplication by a contractive matrix conserves Lipschitz property?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions, contraction-operator

I have seen this argument in a paper and I wanted to ask why this is correct.

Suppose that we have a vector $v(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and we know that $\|v(x)\|^2_2$ is $\alpha$-Lipschitz. We apply a [contractive matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory)) $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to $v(x)$. Why is the $\ell_2$ norm squared of this new vector $\|A v(x)\|_2^2$ also $\alpha$-Lipschitz?

What happens if we know that the vector $v(x)$ is also $\beta$-Lipschitz?

---

My attempt:

Suppose that $v(x)$ is $\beta$-Lipschitz. Let $f(x) = \|Av(x)\|_2^2$. We can write

\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(y)| & = |\|Av(x)\|_2^2- \|Av(y)\|_2^2\\
& \leq |\|A(v(x)-v(y))\|^2_2|\\
& \leq \|A\|_2^2 \|v(x) - v(y)\|_2^2\\
& \leq \beta\|x-y\|_2^2
\end{align}

Therefore, $\|Av(x)\|_2^2$ is $\beta-$Lipschitz if $v(x)$ is $\beta-$Lipschitz. But, can we prove this only using $\|v(x)\|_2^2$ Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: Due to the contractivity of A one has $||Av||\le ||v||$ for any vector v.

Comment: @Mick: The OP is not asking if $x \mapsto Av(x)$ is contractive.

Comment: Which one is Lipschitz continuous $||v(x)||_2$ or $||v(x)||_2^2$ ? In your question you ask whether the $l_2$ norm of the given vector was $\alpha$-Lipschitz, but you write $||Av(x)||_2^2$ which is the square of the $\ell_2$-norm.

Comment: @Mick $\ell_2$ norm squared is Lipschitz continuous. Updated the question, thanks!